# MapperScannerConfigurer config cause illegalArgumentException

Tags: spring, mybatis, mapper

```
<bean id="movieMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.kevinz.ms.mapper.MovieMapper"></property>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

when I combine the spring and mybatis to do a search on DAO, this configuration is working
then I tried the MapperScannerConfigurer to scan all the mappers in com/kevinz/ms/mapper/, there is

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.kevinz.ms.mapper"></property>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

I got the exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to 
>   read candidate component class: file 
>    [E:\workspace\ssm\build\classes\com\kevinz\ms\mapper\MovieMapper.class]; 
>       nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it,I used jdk 1.8,so I update to the spring-framework 4.0 and it works...